# Incorrect scikit-learn linear model prediction with date offset

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to predict time-series data, but by offsetting the result by `date_offset`-timepoints before training and prediction. The reason for doing this is to try and predict `date_offset`-timepoints into the future with the present data. See http://glowingpython.blogspot.co.za/2015/01/forecasting-beer-consumption-with.html for an example.

So in summary:
`data = [1,2,3,4,5]` should predict `result = [2,3,4,5,6]` if `date_offset = 1`

The results on the plot below show the red line being shifted by `date_offset`, and not predicting `date_offset` into the future. No matter how big I make `date_offset`, it keeps shifting and not predicting the last result I have, i.e. `result = 5` (which is already know). In fact, the red line should not shift at all, just loose accuracy the bigger `date_offset` becomes. What am I doing wrong?

See example code and resulting image below:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

date_offset = 1

data = np.array([9330.0, 9470.0, 9550.0, 9620.0, 9600.0, 9585.0, 9600.0, 9600.0, 9430.0, 9460.0, 9450.0, 9650.0, 9620.0, 9650.0, 9500.0, 9400.0, 9165.0, 9100.0, 8755.0, 8850.0, 8990.0, 9150.0, 9195.0, 9175.0, 9250.0, 9200.0, 9350.0, 9280.0, 9370.0, 9470.0, 9445.0, 9440.0, 9280.0, 9325.0, 9170.0, 9270.0, 9200.0, 9450.0, 9510.0, 9371.0, 9499.0, 9499.0, 9400.0, 9500.0, 9550.0, 9670.0, 9700.0, 9760.0, 9767.4599999999991, 9652.0, 9520.0, 9600.0, 9610.0, 9700.0, 9825.0, 9900.0, 9950.0, 9801.0, 9770.0, 9545.0, 9630.0, 9710.0, 9700.0, 9700.0, 9600.0, 9615.0, 9575.0, 9500.0, 9600.0, 9480.0, 9565.0, 9510.0, 9475.0, 9600.0, 9400.0, 9400.0, 9400.0, 9300.0, 9430.0, 9410.0, 9380.0, 9320.0, 9000.0, 9100.0, 9000.0, 9200.0, 9210.0, 9251.0, 9460.0, 9400.0, 9600.0, 9621.0, 9440.0, 9490.0, 9675.0, 9850.0, 9680.0, 10100.0, 9900.0, 10100.0, 9949.0, 10040.0, 10050.0, 10200.0, 10400.0, 10350.0, 10200.0, 10175.0, 10001.0, 10110.0, 10400.0, 10401.0, 10300.0, 10548.0, 10515.0, 10475.0, 10200.0, 10481.0, 10500.0, 10540.0, 10559.0, 10300.0, 10400.0, 10202.0, 10330.0, 10450.0, 10540.0, 10540.0, 10650.0, 10450.0, 10550.0, 10501.0, 10206.0, 10250.0, 10345.0, 10225.0, 10330.0, 10506.0, 11401.0, 11245.0, 11360.0, 11549.0, 11415.0, 11450.0, 11460.0, 11600.0, 11530.0, 11450.0, 11402.0, 11299.0])
data = data[np.newaxis].T

results = np.array([9470.0, 9545.0, 9635.0, 9640.0, 9600.0, 9622.0, 9555.0, 9429.0, 9495.0, 9489.0, 9630.0, 9612.0, 9630.0, 9501.0, 9372.0, 9165.0, 9024.0, 8780.0, 8800.0, 8937.0, 9051.0, 9100.0, 9166.0, 9220.0, 9214.0, 9240.0, 9254.0, 9400.0, 9450.0, 9470.0, 9445.0, 9301.0, 9316.0, 9170.0, 9270.0, 9251.0, 9422.0, 9466.0, 9373.0, 9440.0, 9415.0, 9410.0, 9500.0, 9520.0, 9620.0, 9705.0, 9760.0, 9765.0, 9651.0, 9520.0, 9600.0, 9610.0, 9700.0, 9805.0, 9900.0, 9950.0, 9800.0, 9765.0, 9602.0, 9630.0, 9790.0, 9710.0, 9800.0, 9649.0, 9580.0, 9780.0, 9560.0, 9501.0, 9511.0, 9530.0, 9498.0, 9475.0, 9595.0, 9500.0, 9460.0, 9400.0, 9310.0, 9382.0, 9375.0, 9385.0, 9320.0, 9100.0, 8990.0, 9045.0, 9129.0, 9201.0, 9251.0, 9424.0, 9440.0, 9500.0, 9621.0, 9490.0, 9512.0, 9599.0, 9819.0, 9684.0, 10025.0, 9984.0, 10110.0, 9950.0, 10048.0, 10095.0, 10200.0, 10338.0, 10315.0, 10200.0, 10166.0, 10095.0, 10110.0, 10400.0, 10445.0, 10360.0, 10548.0, 10510.0, 10480.0, 10180.0, 10488.0, 10520.0, 10510.0, 10565.0, 10450.0, 10400.0, 10240.0, 10338.0, 10410.0, 10540.0, 10481.0, 10521.0, 10530.0, 10325.0, 10510.0, 10446.0, 10249.0, 10236.0, 10211.0, 10340.0, 10394.0, 11370.0, 11250.0, 11306.0, 11368.0, 11415.0, 11400.0, 11452.0, 11509.0, 11500.0, 11455.0, 11400.0, 11300.0, 11369.0])

# Date offset to predict next i-days results
data = data[:-date_offset]
results = results[date_offset:]

train_data = data[:-50]
train_results = results[:-50]

test_data = data[-50:]
test_results = results[-50:]

regressor = linear_model.BayesianRidge(normalize=True)
regressor.fit(train_data, train_results)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(regressor.predict(test_data), '--', color='#EB3737', linewidth=2, label='Prediction')
plt.plot(test_results, label='True', color='green', linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the model is not really bad. For instance, when the real value is 10450, it predict 10350, which is really close. And, obviously, the farther in time the predicted point is, the less accurate its predictions, as the variance is growing and sometimes even bias is also growing. You cannot expect the opposite.

Secondly, it is a linear model, so it cannot be absolutely exact when the predicted variable is not linear by nature.

Thirdly, one have to choose a predicted variable with care. For instance, in this case you might try to predict not the value at time T, but the change in value at time T (i.e. C[T]=V[T]-V[T-1]) or the moving average of the last K values. Here you might (or, on the contrary, might not) find out that you are trying to model the so called "random walk" which is hard to predict exactly by its random nature.

And lastly, you might consider other models, like ARIMA, which are better suited for predicting time series.

Answer (score 0):

Adding back the organize_data step:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
def organize_data(to_forecast, window, horizon):
    """
     Input:
      to_forecast, univariate time series organized as numpy array
      window, number of items to use in the forecast window
      horizon, horizon of the forecast
     Output:
      X, a matrix where each row contains a forecast window
      y, the target values for each row of X
    """
    shape = to_forecast.shape[:-1] + \
            (to_forecast.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = to_forecast.strides + (to_forecast.strides[-1],)
    X = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(to_forecast, 
                                        shape=shape, 
                                        strides=strides)
    y = np.array([X[i+horizon][-1] for i in range(len(X)-horizon)])
    return X[:-horizon], y

data = np.array([9330.0, 9470.0, 9550.0, 9620.0, 9600.0, 9585.0, 9600.0, 9600.0, 9430.0, 9460.0, 9450.0, 9650.0, 9620.0, 9650.0, 9500.0, 9400.0, 9165.0, 9100.0, 8755.0, 8850.0, 8990.0, 9150.0, 9195.0, 9175.0, 9250.0, 9200.0, 9350.0, 9280.0, 9370.0, 9470.0, 9445.0, 9440.0, 9280.0, 9325.0, 9170.0, 9270.0, 9200.0, 9450.0, 9510.0, 9371.0, 9499.0, 9499.0, 9400.0, 9500.0, 9550.0, 9670.0, 9700.0, 9760.0, 9767.4599999999991, 9652.0, 9520.0, 9600.0, 9610.0, 9700.0, 9825.0, 9900.0, 9950.0, 9801.0, 9770.0, 9545.0, 9630.0, 9710.0, 9700.0, 9700.0, 9600.0, 9615.0, 9575.0, 9500.0, 9600.0, 9480.0, 9565.0, 9510.0, 9475.0, 9600.0, 9400.0, 9400.0, 9400.0, 9300.0, 9430.0, 9410.0, 9380.0, 9320.0, 9000.0, 9100.0, 9000.0, 9200.0, 9210.0, 9251.0, 9460.0, 9400.0, 9600.0, 9621.0, 9440.0, 9490.0, 9675.0, 9850.0, 9680.0, 10100.0, 9900.0, 10100.0, 9949.0, 10040.0, 10050.0, 10200.0, 10400.0, 10350.0, 10200.0, 10175.0, 10001.0, 10110.0, 10400.0, 10401.0, 10300.0, 10548.0, 10515.0, 10475.0, 10200.0, 10481.0, 10500.0, 10540.0, 10559.0, 10300.0, 10400.0, 10202.0, 10330.0, 10450.0, 10540.0, 10540.0, 10650.0, 10450.0, 10550.0, 10501.0, 10206.0, 10250.0, 10345.0, 10225.0, 10330.0, 10506.0, 11401.0, 11245.0, 11360.0, 11549.0, 11415.0, 11450.0, 11460.0, 11600.0, 11530.0, 11450.0, 11402.0, 11299.0])

train_window = 50
k = 5   # number of previous observations to use
h = 2   # forecast horizon
X,y = organize_data(data, k, h)

train_data = X[:train_window]
train_results = y[:train_window]

test_data = X[train_window:]
test_results = y[train_window:]

regressor = linear_model.BayesianRidge(normalize=True)
regressor.fit(train_data, train_results)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(regressor.predict(X), '--', color='#EB3737', linewidth=2, label='Prediction')
plt.plot(y, label='True', color='green', linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]